# performing few actions when adding a new specific class

Tags: jquery, class

When my page is loading the is no class "changed_value" in the page.
I am adding the calss "changed_value" in several places in the code.

In case of adding this class I wish to perform several actions.

The problem is that  don't wish to write all these actions each time I add the class.

Is there a way to call to some function which will perform the few requested actions in case of adding (at the first time or every time) this new class?

Means, is there a trigger such 'change', 'click' but for adding new class?
Like addedClass?
(I am sure there is no such trigger but I need this idea)...

Thanks in advance!

Miki

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you refactor your common code into a function, which you use to add the class? Something like:

```
function addClass($element) {
    $element.addClass("changed_value");
    // other code here
}
```

And then use it every time you want to add that class:

```
addClass($("my_selector"));
```

Comment: Thanks! it can be a greate idea!

Answer (score 0):

you could something like this

```
function do_something(){
   // do something
}

$('selector').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('class');
    do_something();
});
```